# Sapui5 table column with various control template

Tags: sapui5

I implemented a table which bound to a json model.
I want to manipulate it such as one of the column be with various control types depend on the row value.
For example with some condition some rows of same column has text view control and other has dropdown list control.

I attached a sample image:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could also just create your custom control that renders the control you want based on a property value.

I created a simple example for you: http://jsbin.com/cafumivuco/13/edit?js,output

This has the advantage that only one control is rendered per row and not both while one is invisible.